# Magento 2 How to remove personal information fields(first name, last name) from customer account create page?

Tags: customer-account, magento2.3.1

Please help me to solve it. I have attached the screen short [here](https://prnt.sc/oisceb)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to Override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` to your theme

Path should be like: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml`

Now just remove or comment

```
<legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Personal Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
    <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
    <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
        <div class="field choice newsletter">
            <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
            <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
        </div>
        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```